# IOS MDM-Managed Settings Command return CommandFormatError

Tags: ios, mdm

I receive "CommandFormatError" on Managed Settings commands.

That's what I'm sending as a Settings command:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>123456</string>
    <key>Command</key>
    <dict>
      <key>RequestType</key>
      <string>Settings</string>
      <key>Settings</key>
      <array>
        <dict>
          <key>Item</key>
          <string>VoiceRoaming</string>
          <key>Enabled</key>
          <true/>
        </dict>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks fine from a first glance. Can you post the full text of CommandFormatError from console.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key>
    <string>123456</string>
    <key>Settings</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>Item</key>
        <string>VoiceRoaming</string>
        <key>Status</key>
        <string>CommandFormatError</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Status</key>
    <string>Acknowledged</string>
    <key>UDID</key>
    <string>f2a1e0d59cbf30ec670a4b2af530a40c189de7dc</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
`

Comment: Actually, can you look what device console shows? Quite often it gives more useful information on device itself. Also, Apple dowloads conains profile confiuration which enabled MDM logs, this way device will log even more information

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever figure out what from?

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this same exact issue. Specifically, for VoiceRoaming command on both iPhone (iOS 7 AT&T) and iPad (iOS 8).

According to this 3rd party documentation: http://darthnull.org/media/papers/MDM_CommandReference.pdf

The CommandFormatError is the result of sending the Setting to a device/carrier combination that does not support it.

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN""http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Command</key>
    <key>RequestType</key>
    <string>RemoveApplication</string>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>com.mega888.Release</string></dict>
    <key>CommandUUID</key><string>RemoveApplication</string>
  </dict>
</plis>
```

Comment: Welcome, Mohd. Please pay close attention to your formatting. As you submitted this, it wasn't especially legible. (All of the XML elements were hidden, and so the values were being presented as a concatenated string.) I've attempted to clean it up, _but_ I found an extraneous `<dict>` (start) element. I removed it, but you should confirm that's what you intended.